# Radio Buttons for Edit Summary?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, edit-summary

I don't know about others, but I'm a relatively new user to SO, and I'm just (simply put) too lazy to type in "improved formatting" or "fixed grammar" on my posts after I make edits.

Why not just put radio buttons on the bottom for common items, and have an "Other" button so people can document other changes that aren't already categorized? A single click is a lot easier than reaching for the keyboard.

Comment: Autocomplete based on what you entered before isn't working?

Comment: There's autocomplete? I've never tried it -- I've only put comments when I edit other people's posts, and in those cases, I haven't noticed any autocomplete feature. But I'll look into it and see... does it require reaching for the keyboard?

Comment: There was a script for this *ages* ago... No idea if it still works though: http://blog.bogojoker.com/2008/09/stack-overflow-edit-summary-quicklinks/

Comment: @Shog9: :O that's exactly what I'm looking for... it'd be great if it became a feature (so others can use it too), but judging from the fact that it didn't become one last time, this works too. Thanks; feel free to put this as an answer so I can mark it as one! (Edit: Argh... I have Firefox 4 beta, and Greasemonkey doesn't work on it... looks like I'll have to wait a bit then.)

Comment: @Tim: I did an edit on this very question but still didn't see any autocomplete feature kicking in...

Comment: @Mehrdad: you need [the 0.9.0 version](https://github.com/downloads/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/greasemonkey-0.9.0.xpi) of Greasemonkey (not yet released, unsafe on FF versions <= 4b9)... And I'm not posting it as an answer 'cause I haven't tested it ;-)

Comment: @Shog9: I'll try it... I have 4b10 x64; let's see what happens. :D

Comment: @Shog9: Nope... Greasemonkey works fine (thanks! now my other scripts work!!) but the SO scripts don't work. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: I suspected that might be the case - the site has gone through a lot of changes since that was written. Well, maybe someone will write a new one...

Comment: @Shog9: I've never programmed JavaScript but seeing as how simple the code is, I think I might be able to change it; let's see if I can. >:]

Comment: @Shog9: Well, one problem was that `form-item-info` should be `form-item`. Now I have to see why things aren't displayed the way they should be, since the HTML doesn't look wrong...

Comment: @Shog9: :O I think I got it working!! The only change (other than the one above) is to replace `elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace( regex, "(" + suggestions.join(', ') + ")" );` with `elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + suggestions.join(', ');`.
Try it... like it? :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: yup, that'll do it! Very nice...

Comment: @Shog9: Cool! I just learned some basic JavaScript too, which I'd been wanting to do for quite a while. Killed two birds with one stone... thanks for posting that!! :D (P.S.: JS seems kinda cooler than I thought actually...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: JS is fantastic, easily the best part of this whole wretched "web" fad. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't feel like leaving an edit summary, don't.  Especially if it's obvious what was changed and why.

It's important to use the edit summary when you are changing the question in ways that might make others wonder why you changed it, especially when you are editing other people's questions.

For instance, I might note that I removed a particular tag because it's a redundant, or that using a particular word in the context of the question is confusing and so I changed the terminology.

Comment: Well, the problem is, I *do* want to leave summaries -- even if they're obvious. It's just that I'm too lazy (and I think others might be as well) to move my hand around just to type in two words. :\

Answer (score 1):

While you're making those edits and your hands are already on the keyboard, tab to the summary field and type your reason. Press enter to submit the form. Hitting tab a maximum of two times is a lot easier than reaching for the mouse.

Comment: The problem is, it's not exactly intuitive that you can tab directly to the bottom (since there's so much spacing). I only usually use tab when it's *obvious* what the next selected element is (like when entering a username/password combo), and even if I change my habit, I'm thinking maybe others might find this useful... not sure though.